# How to tell if an Arraylist contains an arraylist of a specific Object in Java

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

I am currently making a storefront simulator, and i'm using nested arraylists (`ArrayList<ArrayList<Item>>`) as my data structure for the store's stock, where each internal Arraylist contains objects of type Item, which is a virtual class I made that the store's product objects inherit from.

I'm trying to  write code to verify that an internal Arraylist exists within the larger arraylist for a new product that's being added to avoid bugs, but i'm having trouble using ArrayList's contains() method in the inner arraylist.

I don't think im explaining myself correctly, so i'll put the code and hope it makes more sense

```
public class Stock {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Item>> items;
    ...

    public void addItem(Item item){
        verifyData(item);
        /* code to add an item to the ArrayList */
    }

    ...
    
     /**
     * Verifies that the specific item has an arrayList for its kind
     * inside the items arraylist. If not, then it will create one
     * @param item the item to be put into the arraylist
     */
    private void verifyData(Item item){
        if (items.contains(new ArrayList<item.getClass>))
            return;

        // If the Map contains the required arrayList, then it shouldn't
        // make it to this point
         items.add(new ArrayList<item.getClass()>());
    }
    ...
```

This code doesn't work, but I hope it conveys kind of what I'm going for. Specifically, `item.getClass()` when adding a new ArrayList doesn't work, so my question is why it doesn't, and how I can implement this (if it can be implemented).

Comment: can use just do "Item" instead of "item.getClass()" if you know that its class is item? Java doesn't really allow storing mixed types in an ArrayList, so you should know the class before hand, which I think is Item right?

Comment: The problem is that Item is a virtual class. The actual things going into the arraylist all inherit from Item. I want them to dynamically go into the proper arraylist, and if it isn't there, to make a new ArrrayList of that object